# How to access FS collections metadata in meteor

Tags: meteor, fs

**My question is solved:**
**It missed this line of code before the insert code:**

```
var fileObj = new FS.File(file);
```

How to access  FS collections metadata in meteor?

I tried: `var result = Images.find({"metadata.gallery._id":curgallery})`

(`curgallery` is the _id of a gallery object) 
Here is my code:

helper:

```
images: function () {
if (Session.get('gallery')) {
  var curgallery = Session.get('gallery')._id;
  var result = Images.find({"metadata.gallery._id":curgallery})
  console.log(result.fetch());//return an empty array
  return result;
};
```

events:

```
 //INSERT IMAGE
'change .fileInput': function(event, template) {
if (Session.get('gallery')) {
  var collection = Session.get('gallery');
  FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
  file.metadata = {owner: Meteor.user()._id,gallery:collection};
  Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {  } ); 
 console.log(file.metadata.gallery._id);//return the _id's gallery
});
  };
```

},

Comment: Are you publishing the contents of the gallery, so the content will be available? Are you waiting for the subscription to load before rendering the template? What results do you get when you open the browser debug console and type `Images.find({})`? Do you get any results? If you see results, what is the value of the `metadata.gallery._id` value? It might be a case where you need to cast `curgallery` to a MongoId before you run the query.

Comment: Please, if you fixed the problem, would you mind sharing with the community what was wrong so others can learn from this too?